# Selection issues when using a Qt proxy model to reparent items under virtual rows

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm attempting to use a proxy model to add virtual rows that will group items in the source model. I almost have something "working", but I can't select the item that is reparented to the virtual row.

Below is the code for the simple test case I've been using to prototype this functionality. This is based on several weeks of scouring the internet for clues, and even AI suggestions, but it's still confusing what's actually going on here.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class VirtualRowProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):

    # Some internal id indicating when its a virtual row
    IS_VIRTUAL = 5

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VirtualRowProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        if self._isVirtualRow(proxyIndex):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        return super(VirtualRowProxyModel, self).mapToSource(proxyIndex)

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        row = sourceIndex.row()
        column = sourceIndex.column()
        parent = sourceIndex.parent()

        if row == 0 and not parent.isValid():
            return self.index(0, 0).child(row, column)

        return super(VirtualRowProxyModel, self).mapFromSource(sourceIndex)

    def hasChildren(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if self._isVirtualRow(parent):
            return True
        return super(VirtualRowProxyModel, self).hasChildren(parent)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not parent.isValid():
            return self.createIndex(row, column, self.IS_VIRTUAL)

        return super(VirtualRowProxyModel, self).index(row, column, parent)

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        if self._isVirtualRow(index):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        sourceIndex = self.mapToSource(index)

        if not sourceIndex.parent().isValid():
            return self.index(0, 0)

        return super(VirtualRowProxyModel, self).parent(index)

    def data(self, proxyIndex, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        # if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        #     sourceIndex = self.mapToSource(proxyIndex)
        #     return str([sourceIndex.row(), sourceIndex.data(),
        #                 proxyIndex.isValid(), proxyIndex.parent().isValid(), sourceIndex.parent().isValid()])
        if self._isVirtualRow(proxyIndex):
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                sourceIndex = self.mapToSource(proxyIndex)
                return "-VIRTUAL ROW-"
            if role == QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
                return True
            return None
        return super(VirtualRowProxyModel, self).data(proxyIndex, role)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not parent.isValid():
            return 3
        if self._isVirtualRow(parent):
            if parent.row() == 0:
                return 1
            return 0
        return self.sourceModel().rowCount(self.mapToSource(parent))

    def _isVirtualRow(self, index):
        return index.isValid() and index.internalId() == self.IS_VIRTUAL


def itemRow(name):
    return [QtGui.QStandardItem(name)]


class Ctrl(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ctrl, self).__init__(parent)

        self.window = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.window)

        self.view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.view.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        row1 = itemRow("A")
        model.appendRow(row1)
        row2 = itemRow("B")
        row1[0].appendRow(row2)
        row3 = itemRow("C")
        row2[0].appendRow(row3)

        self.proxy = VirtualRowProxyModel()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(model)

        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.view.expandAll()

        layout.addWidget(self.view)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle("fusion")

    ctrl = Ctrl()
    window = ctrl.window

    window.resize(600, 300)
    window.show()
    window.raise_()

    app.exec_()
```

If you run this, item "A" is reparented under a virtual row, but it is unselectable. However, B and C are selectable.

I'm unsure if this general approach is correct, so if you have a better suggestion for this, let me know. I've found some C++ examples of proxy models that do groupings of item models, but they are very large and confusing to me as well.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not completely sure about what you want to do. Do you want to add *any* item of the source model as a *further* top level "virtual" item? If you don't mind, may I ask you what would be the final purpose of this? Also, sorry if I'm being blunt, but from what you're writing, it seems that you're trying to do what you want to achieve mostly by trial and error, without really understanding the underlying aspects. It's not like that doing that is completely wrong in principle, but Qt item models are not immediate, and if overriding virtual indexes in a 2d model is already quite difficult, the->

Comment: ->complexity of a 3d (tree) model makes that more *exponentially* problematic. The immediate question, then, is: before "scouring the internet for clues" and, most importantly, asking help to an AI (which is probably not yet ready for such level of complexity, unless it's been specifically and carefully trained), did you carefully study the whole documentation about [Qt model/view programming](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) and improved your experience with more simpler examples, in order to practically understand how they work? Because, if not, then you are not starting good.

Comment: Yes, I'm very experienced with model/view programming, however I've never needed to change the structure of a tree with a proxy model. In this case I have a hierarchical data structure that I'm using a tree view and a standard item model to visualize. We have a need to visualize top-level items grouped by a particular property (by column and role for example). I do not want to change the source model in order to add these, so it makes sense to do this in a proxy model. The code I attached is the simplest example I could come up with of this situation.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being rude, but your experience seems insufficient, at least with 3D models. Your issue is *at least* caused by an insufficient implementation of `index()`, which doesn't consider the reparenting of child indexes (Qt "fails" to see that, and that's an indirect bug, but that's irrelevant): just try to add a further top level element to your base model (`model.appendRow(itemRow('X'))`) and you'll see that it won't be shown; that may be a "bug", but that's just caused by a wrong implementation: the real bug is that it doesn't raise an exception with an inconsistent model.

Comment: Tree models require an exponential step in the implementation (normally, by using recursive functions) and proxy models can only rely on *existing* indexes. If you want to create "virtual" indexes, you must provide a further implementation that properly creates unique *new* indexes for new "reparented" items, as the `createIndex()` used for top level items alone is insufficient. What you want to achieve *is* doable, but you need to create artificial index ids (or pointers) for any items, not top levels alone. A possible solution would probably not use a QStandardItemModel but a custom one.

Comment: You could eventually create a "virtual" model that uses possible filtering options (as long as those filters are static and previously known), unique node objects that may be shown in different *filtered* parents, and then use a proxy model to filter the results. Alternatively, just use a basic data model and *query* it. You could even consider using a basic sqlite memory model and implement a "manual" filtering, then use QtSql classes to query it.